# AngularJS : convert a string into a html template with directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I’m working on a web application project. When I started it, 1 year ago, i was a total noobie in coding (I knew nothing j.s.).
 Now, i’m on the verge of publishing it but it misses the biggest feature.

The project is developped with Angular 1.5. It’s an « editable wysiwyg wiki application » to present a fantasy world : I write an article and I post it. 
 This article contains sentences composed of : 

=> Standard texts

=> clickable links.

=> This clickable link opens a popup with a little definition

=> this popup contains a « know more » link 

=> this « know more link » redirects to another (url) article.

And that’s my problem : I don’t know how to go about it.  Here is the way the text is formatted :

```
var str = "Circa hos dies #Lollianus primae~lollianus# 
lanuginis adulescens, tribus pacataeque centuriae et 
#nulla suffragiorum~nullasuffragiorum# 
certamina set Pompiliani redierit securitas temporis";
```

I want to capture the string between the # characters, then split this string in 2 : the text is before the tilde character, the link comes after.
 I want the output to look like this :

```
<span>  Circa hos dies </span> 
<a popup-directive link="lollianus" > Lollianus primae </a>  
<span> lanuginis adulescens, </span> 
<span>  tribus pacataeque centuriae et </span> 
<a popup-directive link="nullasuffragiorum" > nulla suffragiorum </a>  
<span> certamina set Pompiliani redierit securitas temporis </span>
```

I tried many things but I can only do so much.

Am I being clear enough in my explanations ?

Can you help me go further ? I lost so much time already and i’m totally stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = "Circa hos dies #Lollianus primae~lollianus# lanuginis adulescens, tribus pacataeque centuriae et #nulla suffragiorum~nullasuffragiorum# certamina set Pompiliani redierit securitas temporis";
var split = str.split(/[#]/g);
var elements = [];
for (var i in split){
  console.log(split[i]); 
  if (split[i].indexOf('~') !== -1){
    // this is a link
    var link = split[i].split('~')[1];
    var content = split[i].split('~')[0];
    elements.push("<a popup-directive link=\""+link + '\">' + content +  "</a>");
  } else {
    elements.push("<span>" + split[i] + "</span>");
  }
}
```

Now pop these elements into your DOM using

`document.createElement(htmlToElement(elements[0]));`
`document.createElement(htmlToElement(elements[1]));`

Answer (score 0):

Simple example and you can change it :)

```js
var regex = /#(.*?)#/g;
var str = `Circa hos dies #Lollianus primae~lollianus# 
lanuginis adulescens, tribus pacataeque centuriae et 
#nulla suffragiorum~nullasuffragiorum# 
certamina set Pompiliani redierit securitas temporis`;
var tempVal = "ANCHORLINK";
while ((matchs = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (matchs.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    matchs.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        if(groupIndex == 0)
           str = str.replace(match, tempVal);
        if(groupIndex > 0) {
            var title = match.split("~");
            str = str.replace(tempVal, `<a href="${title[1]}" >${title[0]}</a>`);
        }
    });
}
var result = document.getElementById("result");
result.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to both of you, it helped me a lot.

I’ve changed my methodology accordingly. I do not want to add the url directly between the # anymore. I call a service which enables me find the correspondance between the text of the link and a referential which I created.

I therefore created a referential :

referential.json

```
{
  "lollianus_primae" : {
    "link" : "lollianus",
    "content" : "torvum renidens fundato pectore mansit inmobilis nec se incusare nec quemquam alium passus et tandem nec confessus nec confutatus..."
  },
  "nulla_suffragiorum" : {
    "link" : "nullasuffragiorum",
    "content" : "torvum renidens fundato pectore mansit inmobilis nec se incusare nec quemquam alium passus et tandem nec confessus nec confutatus..."
  },
  "exploratius" : {
    "link" : "exploratius",
    "content" : "torvum renidens fundato pectore mansit inmobilis nec se incusare nec quemquam alium passus et tandem nec confessus nec confutatus..."
  },
  }
```

Then I created the directive which enables formatting each piece of text (is that a span ? or a link ? if so, I add the the addActionToLink directive to it).

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('project')
    .directive('formatText', formatText);
  /** @ngInject */
  function formatText($compile) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace:true,
      scope : {
        texte : '='
      },
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
          if (scope.texte.indexOf('_') !== -1){
            // this is a link
            var link = scope.texte;
            var content = scope.texte.replace('_', ' ');
            elem.replaceWith($compile('<a add-action-to-link id="'+link+'">' + content +  "</a>")(scope));
          } else {
            elem.replaceWith($compile("<span>" + scope.texte + "</span>")(scope));
          }
      }
    };
    return directive;
  }
})();
```

The addActionToLink directive adds a possible action to the element .
In case an action is taken, it sends information to the service in charge of opening and feeding the popup

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('project')
    .directive(addActionToLink, addActionToLink);

  /** @ngInject */
  function addActionToLink(dimensionsService, DefinitionService) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        if (dimensionsService.estUnFormatDesktop()) {
          elem.bind("mouseover", function () {
            console.log(attrs);
            DefinitionService.recupereReferential (attrs.id).then(function (res) {
              DefinitionService.ouverturePopupEttransmissionInfosSurCetteDefinition(res.data, attrs, elem[0]);
            }) ;
          });
        } else {
          elem.bind("click", function () {
            console.log(attrs);
            DefinitionService.recupereReferential (attrs.id).then(function (res) {        DefinitionService.ouverturePopupEttransmissionInfosSurCetteDefinition (res.data, attrs, elem[0]);
            });
          });
        }
      }
    };
    return directive;
  }
})();
```

This is what the template looks like :

```
<p>
     <ng-bind ng-repeat="text in page.text track by $index" format-text texte="text"></ng-bind>
</p>
```

The service retrieving the information and opening the popup is still under building.
One again, thanks you so much. I'm not stucked anymore.